Keyboard doesn't work after suspend in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Help! My Dell Latitude 3340 laptop running Ubuntu has a problem. When I wake it up from Suspend mode, the keyboard stops working, but the touchpad mouse still works. The only way to get my laptop back to normal and use again is by forcefully powering it off with the button. How can I fix this?

Have you figured this out? I'm experiencing a similar situation. But I'm my case, I have a touch screen so I can enter my password using it. The big problem is that the physical keyboard doesn't work after loging in

I had a similar problem with a Dell XPS13-9370 on Ubuntu 22.04. I think the problem was related to a bad external USB mouse. With a new mouse, I've not seen the problem in the last few days.
When I did have the problem, I was able to run "xinput" via the touchpad (copy/pasting from a previous text entry) and I could see the "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" did not load after the suspend. I'm guessing the bad USB mouse interfered with proper re-loading of the keyboard.
